# I wish to grab the AVCaptureConnection audio and enable / disable it when i need too without having to add / remove the input without lag

Tags: xcode, avcapturesession

The title says it all. Not sure what to do about the lag. When I say lag, it seems that when you try to change the state of a connection (the connection.enabled state), it will freeze the avcapturesession to make the changes. Anyway around this? Here is the code I am currently using to grab my audio connection and to change the state. If I run this function before I start recording, it will freeze for a second, I then turn it off after it is done recording but that adds another second of freezing. This is not a great user experience.

```
func EnableDisableAudioDevice(enableAudio :Bool)
{
    var audioInput :AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    if (enableAudio) {
        for input in appDel.captureSession.inputs as! [AVCaptureDeviceInput]
        {
            if input.device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
            {
                audioInput = input
                break
            }
        }
        if (audioInput != nil) {
            for conn in audioInput!.ports as! [AVCaptureInputPort]
            {
                if conn.mediaType == AVMediaTypeAudio
                {
                    conn.enabled = true
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for input in appDel.captureSession.inputs as! [AVCaptureDeviceInput]
        {
            if input.device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
            {
                audioInput = input
                break
            }
        }
        if (audioInput != nil) {
            for conn in audioInput!.ports as! [AVCaptureInputPort]
            {
                if conn.mediaType == AVMediaTypeAudio
                {
                    conn.enabled = false
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I was able to figure out that adding audio input does not seem to be the reason the recording is showing, it is because of my AVCaptureMovieFileOuput. If you add that output to your capture session before recording & then add the audio input, it will say you are recording. Not sure if intended or a bug though. Still having issues trying to find a solution to why it locks up the app when adding the output.

Thanks

Comment: I assume this is not possible because capturesession automatically runs on the main thread, it would be nice to even do this in a background thread so the session does not freeze at all then just do what i need after the audio state has changed.

Comment: I know there is a way around this as I have seen it done with snapchat, I tried dispatch_async, is there another way using a background thread? I have yet to figure this out.